# Omega theme showing 404 on iPhone

Tags: http-request

I have a site on my local server which is served by Apache using virtual hosts. I am using an omega sub-theme. On the desktop everything works fine.  I try to browse to the site via the iPhone by changing the web proxy setting to point to my server. That works and I get to my site via Safari on the phone. Every link I go to on the site gives me a page not found. I'm using views on the site as well.  Looking at the Apache access log I see the entry for Safari that results in a 404 and then Chrome when I browse on my laptop which succeeds.

Any thoughts on where I should start looking for the problem?

```
octopus.dev:80 192.168.1.106 - - [01/Oct/2012:11:00:52 -0500] "GET http://octopus.dev/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5756 "http://octopus.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3"
octopus.dev:80 192.168.1.147 - - [01/Oct/2012:11:01:30 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7475 "http://octopus.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
octopus.dev:80 192.168.1.147 - - [01/Oct/2012:11:01:31 -0500] "GET /sites/default/files/videos/original/output_file_2.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 390 "http://octopus.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
octopus.dev:80 192.168.1.147 - - [01/Oct/2012:11:01:31 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 661 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4"
```

Comment: Can you browse directly to an image, or other asset not managed by Drupal?

Comment: Yes.  Also it looks to be a views related issue since I can see the rest of my page including the sidebars. The view just doesn't give any results and gives a page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to install and configure a proxy server and point my iPhone to it.  I installed squid on the ubuntu box via apt and then on the iPhone under the wireless settings pointed it to the proxy.